# how do code this to get similar output, but in a vertical line; this is my output

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

```
def main():
    myfile = input("Please enter a File: ")
    open_file = open(myfile, "r")
    mylexicon = {}
    mytext = open_file.readlines()
    acc = 0
    for line in mytext:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in mylexicon:
                mylexicon[word] = 1
            else:
                mylexicon[word] = mylexicon[word] + 1
    mylexicon = mylexicon.readline()
    print(mylexicon)

main()
```

The above code produces the output:

```
{'mouse': 2, 'last': 1, 'and': 1, 'jumped': 1, 'over': 1, 'Zippy': 1, 'the': 2, 'cat': 3, '1': 1, '2': 1}
```

But I want it listed in a vertical line.

Comment: `mylexicon.readline()` should throw an `AttributeError` so I doubt that you would even reach the print line

Answer (score 0):

use (you can add the colon and quotes if you like...)

```
for word, number in mylexicon.iteritems():
    print(word, number)
```

instead of

```
print(mylexicon)
```